# Slug: German "Umlauts" (beyond limitAutoSlugsToAscii) // db storage

Tags: craft4, slug

Is there a chance to avoid German "Umlauts" (äöüß) for the slug?

I'm aware of this: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#limitautoslugstoascii
But the editors can edit the slug of existing entries -> that is the point where unwanted "Umlauts" can be produced ... :(

Btw: Where is the slug stored in database? Can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

> But the editors can edit the slug of existing entries -> that is the point where unwanted "Umlauts" can be produced ... :(

Right - the config setting you linked to only applies to auto-generated slugs. Content editors can manually change them at will.

If you want to change that behavior, you'd need to write a custom module/plugin.

> Btw: Where is the slug stored in database? Can't find it.

Assuiming we're talking about Craft 4, that'd be the `slug` column in the `element_sites` table.

Comment: Tank you, Brad! :)